# Website not doesn't scale to fit mobile or tablet devices

Tags: responsive-design

Well, I can't release the URL for the site (not live yet), I was running into issues where the website won't scale to the device screen. For instance, I want the entire website to fit on a mobile, and tablet device without user having to manually scale it down. However, when you view the site, it's zoomed in. Below is the viewport tag I'm using. Any ideas?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no max-device-width value for width. It has to be only device-width. So it should look like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Ok, error on my part. I've changed it back to the above, and still no luck.

Comment: Then please post the HTML and CSS